# CookieProvider для gridPanel внутри TreePanel

Tags: extjs

Слева есть меню навигации(Ext.tree.TreePanel) с сообщениями, папки "входящие", "отправленные", "черновики" и т.д. В центре окна(Ext.grid.GridPanel) отображаются эти сообщения, где поля "наименование", "от кого", "кому" и т.д. находятся в отдельных столбиках. 
Задача: запомнить расположение столбцов/скрытие их. Решил идти через Ext.state.CookieProvider(), соответсвенно добавив stateId для gridpanel и указав stateful: true. По-умолчанию открывается вкладка "входящие". Все отлично работает, но при обновлении страницы при нажатии на другие вкладки данные остаются из вкладки "входящие". Расположение/скрытие столбцов сохраняется. После очистки куки все снова работает до первого f5 или выхода из личного кабинета. Как решить?

Answer (score 0):

все отлично работает ).. 
я так понимаю что панель GridPanel одна для всех типов сообщений ?!.. и содержание данной панели сохраняется по индикатору stateId. 
при переходе из одной вкладки в другую сделай сохранение состояния под разными идентификаторами
Ext.state.Manager.getProvider().set(GridPanel.stateId+'_In',GridPanel.getState());

Comment: Это не ответ на вопрос.

Comment: это не ответ, это направление

Comment: Ну да, но Вы используете поле "ответ", где предположения, уточнения и т.п.  не желательны. Попробуйте отрадактировать, что бы выглядело как ответ на вопрос затронуты автором топика.